# springboot backend to backend with SAML sso, keycloak idp, delegate user identity

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak, saml

My situation is:

```
A = browser; B = springboot backend; C = another springboot backend     
A => B, login okay  
A => C, login okay  
A => B, than A => C, login only once (SSO), okay
```

**A => B => C**, this is the question

- both backends configured as SP and two different SP
- IDP is Keycloak
- SSO is SAML

How could i pass the logged in user data/assertion?
I would like that C process the request as it was executed by the user who called "A" .

I have to configure `RestTemplate` somehow, but I found nothing usable.